# Get the current ScheduledJob name

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I  created a ScheduledJob using the command Register-ScheduledJob -ScriptBlock {...}. This ScheduledJob executes a ScriptBlock. How can I retrieve the name of the currently running ScheduledJob from the ScriptBlock?

E.g.

```
Register-ScheduledJob -ScriptBlock { $CurrentScheduledJob | Out-File -FilePath ScheduledJob.txt}
```

The task in the Windows Task Scheduler is running the command:

> powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -Command
>   "Import-Module PSScheduledJob; $jobDef =
>   [Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobDefinition]::LoadFromStore('asdfdsafsdf',
>   'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs');
>   $jobDef.Run()"

I tried to save the variable $jobDef but it is empty.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe $CurrentScheduledJob.Name would work. You should provide more code to indicate where $CurrentScheduledJob comes from.

Comment: $CurrentScheduledJob does not actually exist. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a ScheduledJob and exported all variable and environment variable and did not find the name or id of the job.

I found a work around:

```
$jobName = 'testName'
Register-ScheduledJob -ScriptBlock { param($name)
         $name | out-file C:\name.txt
    } -name $jobName -ArgumentList @($jobName)
```

If using a parameter is not a solution for you, and you absolutely must retrieve it at run time, then this is a feature request.  You can ask for this at the [PowerShell user voice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell)

Comment: It does not work for me because I need to find out the name of the job at the execution time. Here it will be retrieved at the "job registration".

Comment: It's not retrieved at job registration.  It's set at job registration.  As explained in the answer, there is no practical way to retrieve it at runtime if you do not pass it in as a parameter.  

Please update your question with the additional detail on how this solution fails.